# Appending to 2D lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I've encountered what I think is a strange behavior in Python, and I'd like somebody to explain it if possible.

I've created an empty 2D list

```
listy = [[]]*3

print listy

[[], [], []]
```

The following works as I'd expect:

`listy[1] = [1,2]` yields `[[], [1,2], []]`

`listy[1].append(3)` yields `[[], [1,2,3], []]`

However, when I append to one of the empty lists, python appends to ALL of the sublists, as follows:

`listy[2].append(1)` yields `[[1], [1,2,3], [1]]`.

Can anyone explain to me why this behavior occurs?

Comment: I wonder how many times per month this gets asked.  Surely this is one of the all-time most frequently asked questions about Python (and not just on Stack Overflow).  From the FAQ in the official Python docs:  [How do I create a multidimensional list?](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You haven't created three *different* empty lists. You've created *one* empty list, and then created a new list with three references to that *same* empty list. To fix the problem use this code instead:

```
listy = [[] for i in range(3)]
```

Running your example code now gives the result you probably expected:

```
>>> listy = [[] for i in range(3)]
>>> listy[1] = [1,2]
>>> listy
[[], [1, 2], []]
>>> listy[1].append(3)
>>> listy
[[], [1, 2, 3], []]
>>> listy[2].append(1)
>>> listy
[[], [1, 2, 3], [1]]
```

Comment: This makes so much sense.  Thanks.

Comment: this is the most bizarre functionality I have come across in Python. seems almost like a bug.

Answer (score 19):

`[[]]*3` is not the same as `[[], [], []]`.

It's as if you'd said

```
a = []
listy = [a, a, a]
```

In other words, all three list references refer to the same list instance.

Answer (score -3):

Came here to see how to append an item to a 2D array, but the title of the thread is a bit misleading because it is exploring an issue with the appending.

The easiest way I found to append to a 2D list is like this:

list=[[]]

> list.append((var_1,var_2))

This will result in an entry with the 2 variables var_1, var_2. Hope this helps!