# Initializing Multi-Dimensional List Python Reference Issue

Tags: python, list

If I create a two dimensional matrix as follows:

```
n = 5
m = 5
l = [[0] * n] * m
l[0][0] = 1
print(l)
```

will output:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Why? why are all the sub-lists first elements being set to 1??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745562/appending-to-2d-lists-in-python

Comment: `l = [[0] * n for i in range(m)]`